# CloudFormation - Delete a stack permanently

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

After I delete stacks in CloudFormation, the stacks stay in cloudformation under "Deleted".

Is there a way I can completely remove all deleted stacks and get a clean cloudformation on my project?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are stuck with seeing them in the history for 90 days.  This command talks about how you can get info on them: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-describing-stacks.html

> The aws cloudformation list-stacks command returns information on
> deleted stacks for 90 days after they have been deleted.

There is no way to remove them from that history on your own other than to wait for 90 days.

Comment: 90 days is acceptable as long as they are eventually removed